# QGIS: "Wikimedia unlabelled layer" opacity

Tags: qgis, basemap, transparency-opacity

I'm using QGIS and I want to show a section of the basemap "Wikimedia unlabelled layer" (from the OpenLayers plugin) in full colouring.
But even if in the Properties box opacity is set to 100, still the map is very pale and colourless.
Is there a way to enhance colour quality? Maybe I have to use another similar OSM-file?

Comment: If you have no control over a source (for example it is a wash out raster intended as a background) it is possible to use globalcompositeoperation in OpenLayers to enhance the colour.  This example uses an overlay operation with a gray blend to change the colour intensity https://codesandbox.io/s/globalcompositeoperation-fktwf  It might also be possible to use css filters.